# A nil pointer is sent to chan, but a "non-nil" received

Tags: go, null

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    errChan := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        var e *exec.Error = nil
        errChan <- e
    }()
    err := <-errChan
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err != nil, but err = %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

The output is weird: `err != nil, but err = <nil>`
Try it here: http://play.golang.org/p/_iyh0m7O1a

Comment: I think this piece of doc could help too: http://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Comment: The channel has nothing to do with it. Just do `var err error = e`, and you will see that `err` is not `nil`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem lies in that the value passed into the channel as a error interface is not `nil`, but rather a `exec.Error` pointer which points to nil.

The program will behave correctly if you change:

```
go func() {
    var e *exec.Error = nil
    if e == nil {
        errChan <- nil
    }
}()
```

This is the appropriate way to solve the problem because the idiomatic way to report that no error occurred is by passing a nil error interface.

However, if you want to change the main instead (maybe because you use a third party package which makes the mistake of returning pointers set to nil), you will have to either do a type assertion to the specific type (*exec.Error) and then check if it is nil, or else use the reflect package.

**Example using reflect to check for nil:**

```
func IsNil(i interface{}) bool {
    // Check if it is an actual nil-value
    if i == nil {
        return true
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    switch v.Kind() {
        // Only the following kinds can be nil
        case reflect.Chan, reflect.Func, reflect.Interface, reflect.Map, reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice:
        return v.IsNil()        
    }

    return false
}
```

Working example: http://play.golang.org/p/rpG1PVTwwM

You can find a discussion about it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/QzVDKv7p0Vs

Comment: Supposing you don't change the part that write in the channel, how would you change the `if` test ?

Comment: Good suggestion. I will write a function to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: This post is just to have a bit more insight into a potentially confusing problem.
>   **Using a channel of type** `error` **is the idiomatic way to send errors.**

Another way around this would be to change the channel signature and explicitly say that is a channel pointer to error instead of a channel of interface errors:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    errChan := make(chan *exec.Error)
    go func() {
        var e *exec.Error = nil
        errChan <- e
    }()
    err := <-errChan
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err != nil, but err = %v\n", err)
    } else {
    fmt.Printf("err == nil\n")
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/l6Fq8O0wJw